# Dynamically modifying the url of a layui upload does not take effect the first time

Tags: javascript, file-upload

```
var uploadEle = upload.render({
  elem: '#uploadFile',
  url: '/upload'
  before: function (obj) {
      obj.preview(function (index, file, result) {
         uploadEle.config.url = "/newUpload";
         uploadEle.config.data ={
            fileName:file.name
         };
      }
  }
})
```

The above code does not take effect after the modified url and data are uploaded for the first time;
Subsequent uploads are valid

I want the first changes to take effect